# reversible float sort in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, sorting

I need to sort some arrays of floats, modify the values, and then construct an array with the original ordering, but the modified values.

In R, I could use the `rank()` and `order()` functions to achieve this:
`v` a vector
`v[order(v)]` is sorted
`v[i]` goes in the `rank(v)`th spot in the sorted vector

Is there some equivalent of these functions in the standard c or c++ libraries? A permutation matrix or other way of encoding the same information would be fine too.
O(n) space and O(nlogn) time would be ideal.

Comment: Does "operate on the values" means that they change ?

Comment: Yes it does. I've edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the equivalent to the `rank` function in C++: it's called [nth_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/) and can be applied on any model of [Random Access Container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessContainer.html) (among which `vector` and `deque` are prominent).

Now, the issue seems, to me, that the operate on values might actually modify the values and thus the ranks would change. Therefore I would advise storing the ranks.

1. `std::vector<float>` to `std::vector< std::pair<float, rank_t> >`
2. Sort the `vector` (works without any predicate)
3. Operate on the values
4. `std::vector< std::pair<float, rank_t> >` to `std::vector<float>`

Unless of course you want `nth_element` to be affected by the current modifications of the values that occurred.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I think storing an array of pointers before sorting might be better performance-wise though.

Comment: Hum.. yes it could. `std::vector<float>` to `std::vector<float*>`, sort the pointer version and operate on it.

Comment: For a simple data type, I don't see how using pointer indirection will help performance.  You are going to be taking two memory hits per access to compare where your swap operation will still be a simple 4 byte swap on a 32bit machine.  Sorting via pointers only helps if the cost of the swap the original data type is larger than the cost of swapping pointers.

Comment: But on the other hand you don't have to generate a ranked vector. Honestly I think it's worth checking rather than arguing over it. And with luck (if it's small enough), none will seem faster anyway.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to avoid the overhead of using vectors, since none of their other features are useful here, and I half expected to have to use doubles instead (and have since made that change).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

you can stuff your float into a struct that also holds an int, build an array of these structs and store the position of each element in the int field. use the stl sort with a compare function that operates on the float field for your first step, perform your calculations, then sort with a compare function that operates on the int field to get back your original order.

there might be a better way to do this, i'm not really a c++ guy

Comment: and a brief addendum, you could skip the clumsiness of dealing with a struct and create an array of pointers to your original array of floats. write a comparison function that sorts based on the value the float * points at, do your calculations using the pointer array, and you will never have lost your original order

Comment: Thanks, I had originally considered a similar idea, but wanted to avoid sorting twice. Storing the array of pointers seems like it would work best for what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to copy the arrays before sorting them, and restore them when you've finished. Only do something more complicated if speed is an issue.

In C++, you could sort an array of indices using a custom comparator to compare the array values, something vaguely like this (not tested, and assuming the floats are in a vector):

```
class Comparator
{
public:
    explicit Comparator(const std::vector<float>& array) : array(array) {}
    bool operator()(size_t a, size_t b) {return array[a] < array[b];}
private:
    const std::vector<float>& array;
};

void Example(const std::vector<float> &floats)
{
    std::vector<size_t> rank;
    for (int i = 0; i < floats.size(); ++i) rank.push_back(i);
    std::sort(rank.begin(), rank.end(), Comparator(floats));

    std::cout << "First: " << floats[rank.front()] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Last:  " << floats[rank.back()]  << std::endl;
}
```

Or, at the cost of extra memory, you could build a vector of (float, rank) pairs, and sort that based on the float values. This approach would also work in C using `qsort()`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not to sort the floats, but instead make an array of pointers to the floats, and sort the array of pointers using a comparison function that dereferences the pointers and compares the floats they point to.